# Translating a tabled predicate from b-prolog to gprolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, declarative, knights-tour

For fun I've been attempting to write a Knight's Tour (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) solver in gprolog using Warnsdorf's rule.

I found another SO post asking about efficiency that provided a solution in B-prolog:
[knight's tour efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066294/knights-tour-efficient-solution).

My problem arises with the following section:

```
:- table warnsdorff(+,+,+,+,+,-,-,min).
warnsdorff(R, C, X, Y, Visits, NewX, NewY, Score) :-
    possible_knight_moves(R, C, X, Y, Visits, NewX, NewY),
    possible_moves_count(R, C, NewX, NewY, [(NewX, NewY) | Visits], Score).
```

B-prolog features tabled predicates and gprolog does not. I'm having a great deal of difficulty trying to translate the table section to gprolog. In practice, the function is supposed to return the move from the current position that results in the *least* number of possible moves from the new position (ties are chosen at random).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Ask Dr. Google about "knight's tour prolog". There are many solutions.

Comment: "for fun" similar questions starting to swarm are making me think this is an asignment (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622353/gprolog-knights-tour-using-warnsdorffs-rule and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628413/simulating-knight-movement-using-prolog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, tabling is overkill for this problem. Since the `Visits` lists already is carried on while solving, just use memberchk/2. I get this solution in SWI-Prolog (where, BTW, tabling is implemented, but fails to solve the puzzle using the original coding you linked to):

```
?- time(knight(8, 8, 1, 1, [], Path))...
% 19,973 inferences, 0.019 CPU in 0.019 seconds (100% CPU, 1047591 Lips)
[(1,1),(2,3),(1,5),(2,7),(4,8),(6,7),(8,8),(7,6),(6,8),(8,7),(7,5),(8,3),(7,1),(5,2),(3,1),(1,2),(2,4),(1,6),(2,8),(3,6),(1,7),(3,8),(5,7),(7,8),(8,6),(7,4),(8,2),(6,1),(4,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,2),(5,1),(6,3),(8,4),(7,2),(5,3),(4,1),(2,2),(1,4),(3,3),(2,5),(4,4),(6,5),(4,6),(3,4),(5,5),(4,3),(6,2),(8,1),(7,3),(5,4),(3,5),(4,7),(2,6),(1,8),(3,7),(4,5),(6,4),(5,6),(7,7),(5,8),(6,6),(8,5)]
```

If you want, I can show you the Warnsdorff rule. I've used setof/3, to get the minimum count, joining `possible_knight_moves/7` and `possible_moves_count/6`.

**edit**

as required:

```
warnsdorff(R, C, X, Y, Visits, NewX_, NewY_) :-
    setof((Count, NewX, NewY), (
              possible_knight_moves(R, C, X, Y, Visits, NewX, NewY),
              possible_moves_count(R, C, NewX, NewY, [(NewX, NewY) | Visits], Count)
          ), [(_, NewX_, NewY_)|_]).
```

For clarity, I've renamed the output variables NewX_, NewY_, but that's irrelevant - it worked with the original naming as well.

Comment: I agree, but it does make the code a lot simpler. If you could show your Warnsdorff rule that would be appreciated. I can't quite figure out what you used as the goal in your setoff/3.

Comment: Ah that's rather simple. I suppose trying to think in Prolog at 2 in the morning was not the way to go. I'm having strange issues where possible_knight_moves/7 returns 'no' when the not clause (\+memberchk((NewX, NewY), Visits)) is given a NewX and NewY that is already in the list. It gets about 15 iterations in before this occurs. Did you modify any other sections?

Comment: Correction: it fails because it can't find another move to make. My previous comment didn't make any sense anyways.